# routing in asp.net mvc gives me lenght

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to create this route:

```
http://localhost:28790/Admin/Reporting/Reporting?reportName=MyReportName
```

In order to access to this Controller:

```
public ActionResult Reporting(string reportName){...}
```

For this, i've added this routing in the area:

```
context.MapRoute(
                "Admin_Reporting",
                "Admin/Reporting/Reporting/{reportName}",
                new
                {
                    reportName = UrlParameter.Optional
                }
            );
```

And I've tested this ActionLink

```
@Html.ActionLink(My Link, "Reporting", "Reporting", new { area = "Admin", reportName = "reportingName" })
```

But indeed the result is not what I expect to have:

```
http://localhost:28790/Admin/Reporting/Reporting?Length=9
```

What can I do in order to have the right URL (first URL of the post) instread of this wrong URL (latest URL of the post) ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Your using the wrong overload. It needs to be `@Html.ActionLink(My Link, "Reporting", "Reporting", new { area = "Admin", reportName = "reportingName" }, null)` (the `null` is the html attributes)

Comment: Arghhh I knew I forget something! Thanks man! Put that in answer and I'll validate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You using the wrong overload of `@Html.ActionLink()`. You need to use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493068(v=vs.118).aspx) when you specify `null` for the html attributes (the last parameter)

```
@Html.ActionLink("My Link", "Reporting", "Reporting", new { area = "Admin", reportName = "reportingName" }, null)
```